# sysmessages table issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm experiencing an annoying problem with a table named SysMessages in one of our databases.
When I run a select statement I don't get the contents of this table, but of the sys.sysmessages view in the master database.
A `use [DBNAME]` doesn't help, nor `select * from [DBNAME].dbo.SysMessages`.

I'm in the middle of a migration to a newer SQL Server version.
In SQL Server 2008 R2 I didn't encounter this problem with this database, but in SQL Server 2016 I'm not able to query my own SysMessages table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for [system compatibility views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/system-compatibility-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) from SQL Server 2012+:

> When referenced in a user database, system tables which were announced
>   as deprecated in SQL Server 2000 (such as syslanguages or
>   syscacheobjects), are now bound to the back-compatibility view in the
>   sys schema. Since the SQL Server 2000 system tables have been
>   deprecated for multiple versions, this change is not considered a
>   breaking change.
>
> Example: If a user creates a user-table called syslanguages in a
>   user-database, in SQL Server 2008, the statement SELECT * from
>   dbo.syslanguages; in that database would return the values from the
>   user table. Beginning in SQL Server 2012, this practice will return
>   data from the system view sys.syslanguages.

You're probably going to have to fix your database to not use the same names as  deprecated system tables (now system views in the `sys` schema).

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this *(but you definitely should not do this)* 
is by changing the database collation to be case sensitive. 
This only works if your table is in fact written as `dbo.SysMessages`.

**Consider this example**

```
CREATE DATABASE TEMP2 

USE TEMP2
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SysMessages](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [message] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER DATABASE TEMP2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

**Query with case sensitive collation**

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SysMessages]
```

**Result**

```
id  message
```

**Query with case insensitive collation**

```
ALTER DATABASE TEMP2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;
GO
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SysMessages];
```

**Result**

```
error   severity    dlevel  description msglangid
21  20  0   Warning: Fatal error %d occurred at %S_DATE. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator.    1033
101 15  0   Query not allowed in Waitfor.   1033
102 15  0   Incorrect syntax near '%.*ls'.  1033
...
```

Again, this is only to make the case that you could, but **you definitely should not do this**.

Trying to change the collation can give you errors like this one:

```
The statistics '...' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
```

I tried some other stuff like synonyms and denying select on the `sysmessages` dmv to my login but these did not work.

Comment: Thank you for the research and I'll definitely remember the don't. :-)