# MSSQL Old system tables: is there an hidden synonym? or multiple names?

Tags: sql-server, system-tables

I have tried to create new table named 'SysObjects' on `dbo` schema
here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE sysobjects (Column1 INT );
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE 1 = 0;
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Output is of `sys.sysobjects` view :

```
name        id          xtype uid    info   status      base_schema_ver replinfo    parent_obj  crdate                  ftcatid schema_ver  stats_schema_ver type userstat sysstat indexdel refdate                 version     deltrig     instrig     updtrig     seltrig     category    cache
----------- ----------- ----- ------ ------ ----------- --------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- ------- ----------- ---------------- ---- -------- ------- -------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------

(0 rows affected)

name        id          xtype uid    info   status      base_schema_ver replinfo    parent_obj  crdate                  ftcatid schema_ver  stats_schema_ver type userstat sysstat indexdel refdate                 version     deltrig     instrig     updtrig     seltrig     category    cache
----------- ----------- ----- ------ ------ ----------- --------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- ------- ----------- ---------------- ---- -------- ------- -------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------

(0 rows affected)
```

another example :

```
 SELECT OBJECT_ID('sysobjects'), OBJECT_ID('dbo.sysobjects'), OBJECT_ID('sys.sysobjects')
```

Output:

```
----------- ----------- -----------
-105        -105        -105
```

[Here is an old tables mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and this behaviour is right to all these objects

can anyone explain me how it work ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sysmessages table issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/253735/sysmessages-table-issue)

Comment: the question is similar , but I search a way to identify these case -programmatic

Comment: @mordechai, the `dbo` schema namespace is highjacked by SQL Server in the case of backwards compatibility objects. The object will resolve to the system object in the `sys` schema instead of the user object in the `dbo` schema, essentially hiding the user object. I think this is hard-coded rather than using synonyms.

Comment: I agree with @DanGuzman re: this being handled internally. The following queries point in that direction: `EXEC sp_help N'dbo.sysobjects'; EXEC sp_help N'sys.sysobjects'; SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects WHERE NAME = N'sysobjects';`

Comment: here is a query to find these objects (1675 on my DB) :
`SELECT OBJECT_ID(name),OBJECT_ID('dbo.' + name),OBJECT_ID('sys.' + name),* FROM sys.all_objects WHERE object_id < 0 AND (OBJECT_ID('dbo.' + name) IS NOT NULL OR OBJECT_ID(+name) IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY object_id DESC;`